# I have two python 3 versions running and cant run mkvirtualenv on the cmd using one of them

Tags: virtualenv, python-3.4, python-3.5, virtualenvwrapper

It is telling me that there is no module name mkvirutualenv on one of the version named python35

Comment: Provide some extra information.

Comment: Is virtualenvwrapper installed in both? `pip install virtualenvwrapper`

Comment: Desktop>python35 mkviurtualenv website
python35: can't open file 'mkviurtualenv': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: it is installed i tried downloading it using python35 -m pip install virtualenvwrapper-win  and it said that requirements already satisfied and the path to them

Comment: What's your 2 versions of Python? 3.5 and ?